# How to import variables from a file which can be used in another file which is imported in the same file without importing the file again

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry for the long title.

#### [file1.py]

```
var1=5
```

#### [file2.py]

```
print(var1)
```

#### [file3.py]

```
from file1 import *
import file2
```

How can i make this work?

Comment: You can't. That's not how Python works. At all.

Comment: That's not really how imports work - imported files don't have the context of the file they're imported into. Generally you'd have `file3` call a function from `file2` and pass it the value of `var1` from `file1`.

Comment: ohh. So that's my only option?

Comment: You can import `file1` in `file2` also..

Comment: So i'll have to import the file all the places i need to use it? There is no include function like PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this way, maybe:

[file1.py]:

```
var1=5
```

[file2.py]:

```
def foo(var1):
   print(var1)
```

[file3.py]

```
import file1 as one
import file2 as two
two.foo(one.var1)
```